# How to find a replacement for deprecated method?

Tags: java, android, deprecated, android-music-player

I am new to Android programming.

I have been following a tutorial on creating a Music Player from [this website](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778)

The tutorial calls for a `setAudioStreamType` method from `MediaPlayer` Class which is **deprecated**. Which method replaces this deprecated method in particular? And, is there a source where we can find all deprecated methods and its current alternative?

Here is the code I have where there is a warning about a deprecated method:

```
public void  initMusicPlayer(){
    //set player properties
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Sometime you can find the altenative of deprecated methods reading the `Java Doc`. Otherwise, try searching on official blog / docs / google.

Comment: As always, [**read the documentation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)): *This method was deprecated in API level 26. use `setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes)`*. Downvoted question because "this question does not show any research effort" (quote from tooltip of down-vote button).

Comment: "And, is there a source where we can find all deprecated methods and its current alternative?"  this is a great question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you press CTRL+left click on a method, you find the method declaration. That is where a method is created with its contents and javadoc. Javadoc for deprecated methods often include a `@deprecated` annotation where it mentions the new API and when it was deprecated.

In addition to the javadoc information can also be found in the reference at developer.android.com.

Live example: the Camera class. At the end of the class javadoc it has this:

```
/**
 * (other declarations, and last)
 * @deprecated We recommend using the new {@link android.hardware.camera2} API for new
 *             applications.
 */
```

There you also get a link to the new alternative. If you check the reference at developer.android.com you can also see when it was deprecated (API) and (if you have a new class) you can see when that was introduced. Android has a lot to manage when it comes to API's and what was introduced when especially considering there is a new API each year.

---

As for the Javadoc solution, it can be followed as far as you want. If you have class X, but class X is deprecated. There is a javadoc link to class Y, which replaces class X. For some reason class Y is also deprecated. But there is a javadoc link there that leads to class Z.

Above was a basic example of how you can find the newest replacements, even though the replacement for class X is deprecated. Something to keep in mind in ANdroid programming though, is the fact that you may need the deprecated methods to support lower versions on Android.

Comment: If you wanted a specific API update and not a general tip on how you can find new methods to replace deprecated methods, fields and classes, look at @Bob's answer instead

Answer (score 9):

Use `setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes)` instead of `setAudioStreamType()`.

You can see these details in the Android Developer documentation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)

To follow the latest changes, you can check the Android Developer blog:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/